# Register broadcast receiver via Application context

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, handler

My application class mainly handles current activity's context and other stuff (like showing toast, dialogues and like that).
The other thing, for which I'm using my application class, is for registering broadcast receivers. Not via activity's context, but application's.
What I want to know is:
Will the broadcast receiver will block my UI (Activity's) thread? (I'm calling receiver via Application, so it will make any difference?)
Also, there's an option I can register my receiver via Handler (from application context). Should I do that? Or is there any other approach available, which won't block my main thread?
Thank You.

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` always runs on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiverOnReceive()` is always called within the main thread of its process, unless you explicitly asked for it to be scheduled on a different thread using [`registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter, String, android.os.Handler)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter, java.lang.String, android.os.Handler)).

When it runs on the main thread you should never perform long-running operations in it (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed). You cannot launch a popup dialog in your implementation of `onReceive()`.